# How can I resolve this warning message: "Requires (indirectly) orphaned package: ‘influenceR’"?

Tags: r, package, warnings

When running `devtools::check()`, I receive the following warning message, but I do not know which function of my [rrclust](https://github.com/asam-group/rrclust) package is coming from `influenceR`.

```
❯ checking package dependencies ... WARNING
```

`Requires (indirectly) orphaned package: ‘influenceR’`

I tried to add `influenceR` in the `Suggests:` section of the `DESCRIPTION`, but the same message keeps appearing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is legitimate, you might contact the maintainer of the DiagrammeR package to request a fix.

To know how to contact them you can go the CRAN page : https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DiagrammeR/index.html

There you see a field BugReports with the url of a GitHub repo so this is where you might post your issue.

Now if you need a quick fix, it might work to use a "Suggests" dependency rather than "Imports", in the DESCRIPTION file.

Then in each function that calls {DiagrammeR} you should add something like :

```
if (!requireNamespace("DiagrammeR", quietly = TRUE)) {
  stop("The package {DiagrammerR} is required for this action")
}
```

Or the rlang close equivalent :

```
if (!rlang::is_installed("DiagrammeR")) {
  stop("The package {DiagrammerR} is required for this action")
}
```

I suspect this will work because {dm} suggests {DiagrammeR} and doesn't have these issues as far as I know. The additional advantage is that users who don't have DiagrammeR installed or don't want to install it will still be able to enjoy the not diagram drawing functions of your package.

Comment: +1 for suggest and making functions optional. Imo, it's good practice in general also with packages that got {shiny} enhancements like interactive views or inspectors.

Comment: Thank you @moodymudskipper. I came across an issue which was opened last week regarding this orphaned package in the DiagrammeR GitHub repository, see https://github.com/rich-iannone/DiagrammeR/issues/485. So, this is a known issue and the maintainer of influenceR is working on it.

Comment: Regarding the "Suggests" dependency, I tried to insert `influenceR` in this fied but it did not help. The warning message still comes up. I will wait until https://github.com/rich-iannone/DiagrammeR/issues/485 is resolved. Thanks!

Comment: Great. FWIW I was suggesting to have DiagrammeR as a Suggests, not influenceR

Answer (score 2):

{influenceR} is suggested, at least indirectly via other packages, by a plethora of packages of which your repo uses {utils} and {stats}: *****

```
tools::dependsOnPkgs('influenceR', recursive = TRUE,
                     dependencies = 'all') |>
length()
## [1] 724
```

The only strong dependence on influenceR seems to be incurred by {diagrammeR}:

```
> tools::dependsOnPkgs('influenceR', recursive = TRUE, dependencies = 'strong')
## [1] "DiagrammeR"
```

... so the indirect dependency perhaps happens somewhere among the `plot` or `print` functionalities in you code.

***** as listed with `list.functions.in.file()` from {NCmisc}

Comment: Thank you, @I_O, for this interesting and enlightening answer. Knowing this, what is the best practice to avoid this warning message? Should I add `influenceR` to the `DESCRIPTION` file? If so, in which section (`Depends`, `Imports`, ...) ?

Comment: Haven't had the perseverance to create an R package so far, so I couldn't tell. Anyway, I wonder whether packages would be permitted to override the user preferences of dependency managament during installation. :-?

Answer (score 1):

@I_O is right. `diagrammeR` depends on `influenceR` which does not have a maintainer anymore, see here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/influenceR/index.html

CRAN claims the latest version of `influenceR` was just published not even 2 weeks ago. I suggest to contact the author, given that quite a few people use `diagrammeR` I'd contact the author of `diagrammeR`. He has been active and very helpful on R twitter in recent years.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this in my situation. The R package I'm developing loads a number of packages, and today I received the same error message as the original post (just a different package),

`Requires (indirectly) orphaned package: ‘plotrix’`

However, plotrix was just updated today (literally), and the package I'm developing has been running without any errors until today.

I was able to solve the issue by going through each of the packages imported by my R package, and looking on this page for each package (in this example, the earth package, just change 'earth' to each of the packages imported by your package, and check one at a time):

https://cran.csiro.au/web/checks/check_results_earth.html

The exact warning given by dev tools::check() is right there:

```
Check: package dependencies
Result: WARN
    Requires (indirectly) orphaned package: ‘plotrix’
Flavors: r-devel-linux-x86_64-fedora-clang, r-devel-linux-x86_64-fedora-gcc
```

What the error message is saying is that the earth package is not available for those two systems (r-devel-linux-x86_64-fedora-clang, and
r-devel-linux-x86_64-fedora-gcc), therefore the warning. I'm running MacOS, so it's fine for me, and that's why I did not have any issues.

One solution is to remove that package from my list of imported packages in my R package. I'll notify the maintainers of the earth package, and put it back in once everything is all good with the earth package.